# Lasso Select not working when using with RMB selection (bug?)

Tags: shortcut, customization, selection-tools, select, mouse

Upon installing and launching Blender 2.9 (or 2.8) for the first time, one is presented with this choice: Select with **L**eft **M**ouse **B**utton or **R**ight **M**ouse **B**utton?

Blender 2.9 splash screen on first launch:

[image]

Being comfortable with the traditional RMB selection schema from past versions of Blender, I did not feel compelled to switch to LMB.

The problem is that in doing so, I seem to have lost the ability to Lasso Select. (It worked  in 2.79 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**L-Click-Drag**.)

The [Blender Manual page on Selecting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#lasso-select) states that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**R-Click-Drag** will Lasso Select. So what about users sticking with the traditional RMB selection? Instead of having Lasso Select moved to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**L-Click-Drag** we just lose the ability altogether?

**How can the keymapping be configured to bring Lasso Select functionality back for a R-Click selecting user?**

System configuration: Blender 2.90.0, macOS 10.14.6, "Select With: Right".

Thanks!

Comment: The keymap is some how overwritten by current selecting tool and disable the functionality to trigger that key combination in Lasso select keymap. Shouldn't it been a bug?